# Como provar a quantidade de folhas dessa árvore por indução?

Tags: árvore-binária

Se cada nó não folha de uma árvore binária tem sempre dois descendentes como posso provar por indução que o número de folhas sempre vai ser o número de nós não folha mais um ?

Eu fiz da seguinte forma, porém não sei se posso pensar assim:

**Base**: Seja M uma árvore com um nó não folha K, então o número de folhas L vai ser K + 1, logo L = K + 1.

Como K = 1 então L = 1 + 1 = 2. Oque é verdade.

Porém para provar o passo indutivo tenho que falar que isso vale para um número de folhas qualquer N e provar que vale para este N e para N + 1, e é ai que não consigo sair.

PS: Não sabia se colocava isso aqui ou no MathExchange, achei que se encaixaria mais aqui por querer provar algo relacionado as árvore binárias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, há várias abordagens para resolver este problema. Eu não consegui resolver diretamente, o que pode ter deixado a resposta um pouco confusa(espero que não). Espero que te ajude a ter uma visão melhor do problema.

Em uma árvore completa, cerca de metade dos nós estão no nível inferior. Assim, cerca de metade de todas as pesquisas ou inserções ou exclusões exigem encontrar um nó no nível mais baixo.A Tabela abaixo mostra quantos níveis são necessários para manter um
determinado número de nós.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente a árvore com L níveis tem [2^(L+1)]-1 nós. De maneira mais formal, se fizermos P(L) denotar o número de nós no nível L, então nossa suposição será:

P(L) = [2^(L+1)]-1

Portanto, o número de folhas no nível 3, usando a lógica, por exemplo, será igual a:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

P(L)-P(L-1)

= P(3)-P(3-1)

= P(3)-P(2)

= [(2^(3+1))-1] - [(2^(2+1))-1]

= [(2^(4))-1] - [(2^(3))-1]

= [15] - [7] = 8

Então, dado uma árvore com 3 níveis e 15 nós, teremos 8 folhas e 7 nós não folhas. Um nó folha a mais. Agora, como é possível generalizar que P(L) = [(2^l+1)-1] é sempre válida para qualquer L >=0 a fim de ter segurança para usar a lógica acima?

A base da indução é estabelecer P(0), que resulta a equação
número de nós = P(1) = [2⁽⁰⁺¹⁾]-1 = 1

Agora vamos assumir que nossa premissa é verdadeira para um nível arbitrário k, ou seja, assumimos que:

> P(k) = 2⁰+2¹+2²+2³+2⁴+...+2^k = [2^(k+1)]-1       {1}

e tentaremos mostrar que:

> P(k+1) = 2^(k+1) = [2^(k+1+1)]-1          {2}

A chave para uma demonstração por indução é encontrar uma forma de relacionar o que se deseja mostrar — P(k + 1), equação {2} — com o que assumimos como verdadeiro — P(k), equação {1}. O lado esquerdo
de P(k + 1) pode ser reescrito a fim de destacar o penúltimo termo:

> 2⁰+2¹+2²+2³+2⁴...+[2^k]+[2^(k+1)] ?= [2^(k+1+1)]-1    {3}:

Como assumimos que P(k) na equação {1} é verdadeira, podemos substituir [2^k] na expressão abaixo pelo lado direito da equação {1}, neste caso [2^(k+1)]-1:

2⁰+2¹+2²+2³+2⁴+...+[2^k]+[2^(k+1)]

= 2⁰+2¹+2²+2³+...+[2^(k+1)]-1+[2^(k+1)]

= [2^(k+1)]-1+[2^(k+1)]

= 2*[2^(k+1)]-1

= 2^(k+1+1)]-1

Concluímos que a equação {3} está correta, consequentemente a equação {2} também:

2^(k+1+1)]-1 = [2^(k+1+1)]-1

Este script em python realiza o calculo:

```
def nodes(level):
    return (math.pow(2,(level+1))-1) 
def leaves(height):
    return nodes(height)-nodes(height-1)
```

Fontes:

> GERSTING, Judith L. Mathematical structures for computer science.
>   Macmillan, 2007.
>
> LAFORE, Robert. Data structures and algorithms in Java. Sams
>   Publishing, 2017.